# Getting existing HTML in TR Body to Clear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a Jquery/Ajax call which updates cart details. At the moment I can't get the existing HTML in the cart-body(tablebody) to clear. The actual ajax request works and all items are added to cart but the original HTML entries stay. The particular code is here:

```
         if (data.products.length > 0 ) {

             productRows.html("")
             $(cartBody).empty()
```

Jquery Function

```
  function refreshCart() {
         console.log("in current cart")
         var cartTable = $(".cart-table")
         var cartBody = cartTable.find(".cart-body")
         var productRows = cartBody.find(".cart-product")
         var cartTotal = cartTable.find(".cart-total-sec")
         var productQuantity = cartTable.find(".cart-item-quanity")
         var currentUrl = window.location.href
         var refreshCartUrl = '/api/cart/'
         var refreshCartMethod = "GET";
         var data = {};
         $.ajax({
             url: refreshCartUrl,
             method: refreshCartMethod,
             data: data,
             success: function(data) {
                 console.log("success")
                 console.log(data)

                 if (data.products.length > 0 ) {

                     productRows.html("")
                     $(cartBody).empty()

                     $.each(data.products, function(index, value) {


                         console.log(value)
                         console.log(data.count)
                         cartBody.append("<tr><td>" + value.quantity + " x" + "</td><td>"+ value.name + "</td><td>" + "£" + value.price + "</td></tr>")

                     })
                     cartTotal.find(".cart-total").text(data.total)
                     console.log(data.total)

                 } else {
                     window.location.href = currentUrl
                 }
             },
             error: function(errorData) {
                 console.log("error")
                 console.log(errorData)
             }
         })
     }
```

HTML Form:

```
<div>
    <h4>This is your shopping cart</h4>
    <table class="cart-table">
            <tr>These are the items in your basket and their respective totals</tr><br>
            <tbody class="cart-body">
            {% for item in cart.items %}
            <form method="POST" action='{% url "shopping-cart-remove" %}'>
            {% csrf_token %}    
            <tr class="cart-product"><span class="cart-item-quanity">{{ item.quantity }}</span> x {{ item.product.name }} = {{ item.subtotal }}</tr>
            <input type="hidden" name='id' value='{{ item.product.id }}'>
            <span class='remove-span'><button>remove</button><br></span>
            </form>
            </tbody>
            {% endfor %}

        <tr class="cart-total-sec"><td class="cart-price">{{ cart.total }}</td></tr>
</div>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: When does `refreshCart()` run? Before or after you append the `cat-table`? jQuery shouldn't care about what's inside an element or how an element is created, the element just needs to exist at the time of reference, so if `refreshCart()` is referencing something that doesn't exist yet it won't work as expected. Despite your use of the `<table>` element being obscure you should get the expected results. Changing `var cartBody` to `var cartBody = $('.cart-table').find('.cart-body');` should work, given it is not executed before the `cart-body` element is created in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

First you are making mistake, as i can see there's form in table, on refreshing you will lose that form so i guess you should append items in form not in `.cart-body`.

And for emptying html use `cartBody.html("");` and you don't have to use `productRows.html("")` at all.

Comment: The actual append statement is working, I just can't clear the existing cart body. I changed it to .html("") but the results are the same.

Comment: Hey, you have a problem with your html code, your table isn't rendered at all. All text is outside of table, so when you call empty it won't empty anything because the table is rendered empty and the text is above table.
Something destroys your table, and you have to check what is it.

Comment: Thanks, but I've looked at the code and all the code is enclosed within the table tag. Can you show me an example of what you mean or elaborate further?

Comment: Check with developer tools how its rendered, you closed tags but table gets into problems with tags that doesnt start with tr, i am not at the computer to make image to show ya.

Answer (score 0):

The issue as pointed out by Ultrazz008, was that the HTML was incorrectly formatted. For reference:

```
<table class="cart-table">
    <tbody class="cart-body">
        <form method="POST" class='form-product-ajax' action='{% url "shopping-cart-remove" %}' data-endpoint='{% url "shopping-cart-remove" %}'>
            {% csrf_token %} {% for item in cart.items %}
            <tr class=cart-product>
                <td>{{ item.quantity}} x {{ item.product.name }} {{ item.subtotal }}
                    <input type="hidden" name='id' value='{{ item.product.id }}'>
                    <button class='remove-btn'>remove</button>
                </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>
    <tr class="cart-total-sec">
        <td class="cart-price">{{ cart.total }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```